# Full screenshot not coming in Alert and Report of Apache Superset

Tags: devops, dashboard, apache-superset

whenever I am sending dashboard through report and alert option of Superset 1.1 version the the screenshot of dashboard not coming in the mail pls help me for the same . Thank you

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

adding below lines to schedules.py in superset/tasks might help

window = config["WEBDRIVER_WINDOW"]["dashboard"]
driver.set_window_size(*window)

Note: If ur using a tabs in superset dashboard, superset only captures single tab image

Comment: Is this working for you without adding this line of code ?